# Как правильно считать информацию из массива?

Tags: php

Есть массив, в нём каждый символ,размещен в отдельном индексе. То есть:

```
[ равен [0]
" равен [1]
1 равен [2]
0 равен [3]
```

...и.т.д

**Сам массив:**

```
["1060","dtest",64550]
```

В настоящие время, тут три значения :

**1** - 1060

**2** - dtest

**3** - 64550

**Как правильно** считать значения в массиве?

Comment: я так понимаю, что у вас не массив, а строка, потому у вас так и получается. Приведите пример кода, где это используется, тогда сможем указать на ошибку (скорее всего кавычки вокруг массива достаточно убрать)

Comment: @BOPOH Мне функция это выдаёт. `Yii::$app->request->cookies->getValue('_identity')`

Comment: в куках хранятся только строки

Comment: @BOPOH Вот тут написано что мы можем использовать данные как массив - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/runtime-sessions-cookies.md    `// теперь переменную $cookies можно использовать как массив
if (isset($cookies['language'])) {
    $language = $cookies['language']->value;
}`

Comment: сделайте `var_dump(ВАШ_МАССИВ)` - скорее всего будет строка, если так, то ее можно в массив переделать при помощи `json_decode(ВАШ_МАССИВ, true)`

Comment: @BOPOH var_dump(ВАШ_МАССИВ) - будет строка уже пробовал. А вот это интересно `json_decode`

Comment: @FiR, так там написано не про определенную куку, а про куки вообще, т.е. можно было сделать `$cookie = Yii::$app->request->cookies; var_dump($cookie['_identity'])`, т.е. с куками как с массивом работаете, но там не написано, что так же можно и с отдельной кукой работать

Comment: @BOPOH Да, всё верно. Больше спасибо)

Comment: @BOPOH Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.